# Включение/выключение видео через кнопку

Tags: javascript, html, видео

Есть несколько видео на странице, сделал включение/выключение видео по клику на кнопку или само видео. Если на странице несколько видео, то включается/выключается только первое. Хотелось бы получить универсальную функцию, которая будет работать не через ID видео (не хотелось бы одни и те же идентификаторы на одной странице иметь) и включать/выключать только конкретное видео соответственно.

```js
var video;
window.onload = function() {
  video = document.getElementById("video");
}
$(document).on('click', '.PlayPauseVideo', function() {
  if (video.paused) {
    video.play();
  } else {
    video.pause();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video_with_link">
  <video id="video" width="380px" height="250px" src="video/videoplayback.mp4" class="PlayPauseVideo"></video>
  <input type="button" class="PlayPauseVideo">
</div>
<div class="video_with_link">
  <video id="video" width="380px" height="250px" src="video/videoplayback.mp4" class="PlayPauseVideo"></video>
  <input type="button" class="PlayPauseVideo">
</div>
<script>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id="video"` >> `class="video"`

```
<div class="video_with_link">
    <video class="video" width="380px" height="250px" src="video/videoplayback.mp4" class="PlayPauseVideo"></video>
    <input type="button" class="PlayPauseVideo">
</div>

$(document).on('click','.PlayPauseVideo',function(){
  var video = $(this).closest(".video_with_link").find(".video")[0];
  if (video.paused) {
    video.play();
  } else {
    video.pause();
  }
});
```